# How do I recover my lost Windows 10?

Tags: system-installation, windows-10, data-recovery, ntfs

When I installed Ubuntu 20.04, after everything was done I lost my Windows 10. I am unable to boot into it and my GRUB does not show Windows 10. I need my data badly as I don't have any backup.

[Boot Repair Summary](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/yY3XPX9wmh/)

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Recommended repair: ____________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility will reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of
nvme0n1p2,
using the following options:        nvme0n1p1/boot, nvme0n1p6/boot/efi,
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s  use-standard-efi-file


/boot/efi added in nvme0n1p2/fstab
nvme0n1p2/boot/efi not empty

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub

=============== Reinstall the grub-efi-amd64-signed of nvme0n1p2 ===============

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26

efibootmgr -v from chroot before grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(6,GPT,883ccb28-24dd-4bdb-9a2b-a43e027fe1d7,0x8127000,0x3d0800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

uname -r
5.4.0-26-generic

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.
df /dev/nvme0n1p6
mv /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
cp /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /boot/efi/EFI/Boot/

grub-install --efi-directory=/boot/efi --target=x86_64-efi --uefi-secure-boot
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

efibootmgr -v from chroot after grub install
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(6,GPT,883ccb28-24dd-4bdb-9a2b-a43e027fe1d7,0x8127000,0x3d0800)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
Warning: NVram was not modified.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p2/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS CurrentSession entry (nvme0n1p6/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file) !

============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /grub/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p6: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/BOOT/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg


================================ 1 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS CurrentSession on nvme0n1p2

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic root=UUID=8602cbdb-6e70-405f-9c2e-fc87246ec967 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7


===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS is EFI-compatible, and is setup in EFI-mode for this installed-session.
SecureBoot enabled.

efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(6,GPT,883ccb28-24dd-4bdb-9a2b-a43e027fe1d7,0x8127000,0x3d0800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/mmx64.efi
98bea152fadd26c4e9136916f6cc32a8   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p1/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi
bed45d1c9554cea09924d3814cb7c446   nvme0n1p6/BOOT/fbx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p6/BOOT/mmx64.efi
98bea152fadd26c4e9136916f6cc32a8   nvme0n1p6/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
4487628005555bfd4a4c0a47211e0700   nvme0n1p6/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p6/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
f7a57b08bc7c1c85417ae4cea582d1d4   nvme0n1p6/BOOT/BOOTX64.efi


============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    not-far
nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  grubenv-ok, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p6   : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p6   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p2   : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-has-goodBOOT, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : is-sepboot,   no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : maybesepboot, no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p6   : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 238.49 GiB, 256060514304 bytes, 500118192 sectors
Disk identifier: F31AD3FB-8A65-4B51-8499-D53619D076D5
              Start       End  Sectors  Size Type
nvme0n1p1      2048   3999743  3997696  1.9G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p2   3999744  33574911 29575168 14.1G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p3  33574912 106870783 73295872   35G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p4 106870784 119216127 12345344  5.9G Linux filesystem
nvme0n1p5 119216128 135426047 16209920  7.7G Linux swap
nvme0n1p6 135426048 139425791  3999744  1.9G EFI System

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:256GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:HFS256GD9TNG-62A0A:;
1:1049kB:2048MB:2047MB:ext4::;
2:2048MB:17.2GB:15.1GB:ext4::;
3:17.2GB:54.7GB:37.5GB:ext4::;
4:54.7GB:61.0GB:6321MB:ext4::;
5:61.0GB:69.3GB:8299MB:linux-swap(v1)::swap;
6:69.3GB:71.4GB:2048MB:fat32::boot, esp;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL PARTLABEL
nvme0n1                                                                                              
├─nvme0n1p1 ext4     90a97514-25c0-4435-bef6-08b05f620792 052a5884-1d89-48ef-b82a-b0deeed1fbd8       
├─nvme0n1p2 ext4     8602cbdb-6e70-405f-9c2e-fc87246ec967 a1939e1c-02df-4694-8dc1-b2284000e309       
├─nvme0n1p3 ext4     9c32159e-4ed8-4ee2-942a-3200a1e5f6f2 03def592-43e5-4689-a23a-737772d23660       
├─nvme0n1p4 ext4     43338a6b-cbf3-491d-a8f0-47c1849d490d 7cc26fca-aff4-4102-9c7d-cf57313f7172       
├─nvme0n1p5 swap     ea705563-b645-4ab3-813b-5d76b0d9b706 a6b1be88-4210-44f4-b171-487e1f878a59       
└─nvme0n1p6 vfat     C0DA-04E1                            883ccb28-24dd-4bdb-9a2b-a43e027fe1d7       

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

           Avail Use% Mounted on
nvme0n1p1   1.7G   4% /boot
nvme0n1p2   9.3G  28% /
nvme0n1p3  32.3G   0% /home
nvme0n1p4   4.7G  14% /var

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1 rw,relatime
nvme0n1p2 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
nvme0n1p3 rw,relatime
nvme0n1p4 rw,relatime

====================== nvme0n1p1/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   8602cbdb-6e70-405f-9c2e-fc87246ec967
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-26-generic   8602cbdb-6e70-405f-9c2e-fc87246ec967
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
UEFI Firmware Settings   uefi-firmware
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

================= nvme0n1p1: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
   0.000980377 = 0.001052672    grub/grub.cfg                                  1
   0.149410248 = 0.160428032    vmlinuz                                        2
   0.149410248 = 0.160428032    vmlinuz-5.4.0-26-generic                       2
   0.336093903 = 0.360878080    initrd.img                                     1
   0.336093903 = 0.360878080    initrd.img-5.4.0-26-generic                    1
   0.336093903 = 0.360878080    initrd.img.old                                 1

======================== nvme0n1p2/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=8602cbdb-6e70-405f-9c2e-fc87246ec967 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=90a97514-25c0-4435-bef6-08b05f620792 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p6 during installation
# /home was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=9c32159e-4ed8-4ee2-942a-3200a1e5f6f2 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/nvme0n1p4 during installation
UUID=43338a6b-cbf3-491d-a8f0-47c1849d490d /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=ea705563-b645-4ab3-813b-5d76b0d9b706 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=C0DA-04E1  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1

==================== nvme0n1p2/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

=================== nvme0n1p2: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17123 Apr 15 17:01 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42128 Apr 15 17:01 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Apr 15 17:01 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Apr 15 17:01 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Apr 15 17:01 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Apr 15 17:01 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Apr 15 17:01 41_custom

=================== nvme0n1p6/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 90a97514-25c0-4435-bef6-08b05f620792 root 
set prefix=($root)'/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

Disk partitions:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) or [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix).  Make backups!

Comment: @Nmath My computer does not even show that there is windows 10

Comment: @Nmath Could you look into the report i posted and infer ,please

Comment: post gparted screenshot and also tell if you notice any change in disk partitions.

Comment: Just calm down community will help you. Just add gparted screenshot by editing your question.

Comment: There aren't any partitions in that screenshot that could have a Windows installation on it.  Do you have more than one hard drive?  If this is your only hard drive you might have overwritten Windows when you tried to install Ubuntu.  You can't simply undo that mistake - you'd need to reinstall Windows.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206

Comment: @Nmath So,all is lost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the bearer of bad news but unless your Windows 10 is installed on a 2GB partition (unlikely), it's gone. Did you manually choose the partition structure or let Ubuntu installer take care of it? And did you choose dual-boot / multi-boot during the installation?

Purely from looking at your gparted screenie, I'd say you're only hope of data recovery is using disk recovery tools. Unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Data recovery Using `photorec` you shall need another disk with enough free space to store recovered data.

boot into Ubuntu from USB disk
open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install photorec
```

after completion of installation type `photorec` in terminal and follow instruction from [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step). It is terminal command based and you can select the files you want to recover like. *.JPG, *.pdf, *.doc etc. Read this page procedure carefully before proceeding.

2. Data recovery Using `testdisk` you shall need another disk with enough free space to store recovered data.  Here the benefit is that you can recover the data with your directory structure and same directory/ file names.

boot into Ubuntu from USB disk
open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

after completion of installation type `testdisk` in terminal and follow instruction from [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step). Read instructions carefully. **With `testdisk` command it may be possible for you to recover your Windows partition**.